# Move a range of numbered files and change their value

Tags: shell, mv

I've got numbered files (DSC_0001.jpg to DSC_0065.jpg) on a Linux machine, I know how to move them with `mv DSC_{0001..0065}.jpg dir`.

I have no idea how to move them and change the range of values.

`mv DSC_{0001..0065}.jpg DSC_{0134..1198}.jpg` is not working.

Is there another way to do this ?